# how to create package for module in sitecore application

Tags: package, sitecore, sitecore6, nuget-package, sitecore7

i have created a module for sitecore, i made some changes in sitecore application folder and some
    are added new, so now i want to create package for this module, i create packge using package 
    designer wizard for items & templates in sitecore but now i want to add my customized code in
    the package. can anyone suggest me how to create package for this module. Thanks in advance.

i also read this blog:

```
http://www.sitecore.net/Learn/Blogs/Technical-Blogs/Trevor-Campbell/Posts/2013/02/28-Days-of-Sitecore-Rocks-Package-Creation.aspx
```

Comment: You can also create a package using Sitecore Courier module - https://github.com/adoprog/Sitecore-Courier. Just put all the items  & files into one folder and run the tool.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You add the files from the same Package Designer application as the Items.

From the Ribbon, Select `Files Dynamically` or (more likely) `Files Statically` and then select the files you want to add to the package.

You can then generate the zip as normal.

[image: Sitecore Add Files to Package]

Comment: Just as a side comment, you say you made some changes in the Sitecore Application folder - be careful about making any changes to any default files since they may change between versions esp.

Comment: And here is some general information provided by Sitecore regarding module implementation best practices that may help.
https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/831724

Comment: This can also be done using the Sitecore Rocks extension for Visual Studio. I definitely recommend you check it out as it can make a lot of common tasks easier. I got hung up trying to create a package with it at first, however. I had to install the "Hard Rock Web Service" by right-clicking on my connection to the Sitecore instance in the Sitecore explorer. Check out [this blog series](http://www.sitecore.net/Learn/Blogs/Technical-Blogs/Trevor-Campbell/Posts/2013/02/28-Days-of-Sitecore-Rocks-Intro.aspx) to learn a lot more about what Sitecore Rocks is capable of.